# Why is this getting "Failed to get type for: content://contacts/"

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-contentresolver

I'm stepping through the tutorials in "Professional Android 4 Application Development".  In Chapter 5, there is a simple app that demonstrates picking a contact and printing the result.

After I entered the app and tested it, I got the following error:

> 10-06 11:29:04.596: W/ContentResolver(1073): Failed to get type for: content://contacts/ (URI: content://contacts/, calling user: android.uid.system:1000, calling package is one of: [com.android.keychain, com.android.settings, android, com.android.providers.settings, com.android.inputdevices])

This string is referenced in the following method:

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact_picker_tester);

    Button  button  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pick_contact_button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent  intent  = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Uri.parse("content://contacts/"));
            startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
        }
    });
}
```

I thought perhaps I had done something wrong, so I ran the corresponding example from the [Book source code](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/productCd-1118102274,descCd-DOWNLOAD.html) and got the same error.  Any ideas what might be wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing

```
Intent  intent  = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Uri.parse("content://contacts/"));
```

to :

```
Intent intentContact = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
```

I think your uri is incorrect, which is why its throwing the type error.

Answer (score 2):

I just went through the same sample from this book. The content URI "content://contacts" is invalid and is missing the [authority](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html). It should be defined as

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Uri.parse("content://picker/contacts/"));
```

The authority "picker" is an arbitrary name for the entire provider.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the correct permissions in your android manifest.xml?

You need:

```
android.permission.READ_CONTACTS
```

From http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html